# Error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (arcpy.ListRasters)

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, typeerror

I am trying to extract a raster through a particular shapefile.

```
   import arcpy
   from arcpy import env
   from arcpy.sa import *
   arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
   env.overwriteOutput = True

   #Set the current workspace
   env.workspace = ("C:\thesis\Forests Only Percent Treecover\2003 BSWM Forest")
   env.nodata = "MINIMUM"
   env.compression = "LZ77"

   #This is for extracting the forest areas of hansen percent treecover
   for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*0E.tif", "TIFF"):
       print raster #checking the presence of raster
       outputRasterExtractbyMask = ExtractByMask(raster, "NAMRIA.shp")
       outputRasterExtractbyMask_Name = "forests_only"+raster
       outputRasterExtractbyMask.save(outputRasterExtractbyMask_Name)

   print "Finish"
```

As I print the raster in arcpy.ListRasters to check the presence of raster, this error shows up:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\brentiebark\Dropbox\Python Scripts and mxds\extractbymask.py", line 14, in <module>
 for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*0E.tif", "TIFF"):
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I double checked the directory, and my files are really there. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
env.workspace = ("C:\thesis\Forests Only Percent Treecover\2003 BSWM Forest")
```

with:

```
env.workspace = (r"C:\thesis\Forests Only Percent Treecover\2003 BSWM Forest")
```

The backslash is Python's escape character so when it appears in a DOS path you need to replace it with either a forward slash or double back slashes or just put an r for raw in front of the whole string.

There is also an error where:

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*0E.tif", "TIFF"):
```

should be:

```
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*0E.tif", "TIF"):
```

Comment: I've replaced it, but it just prints the "Finish" string and the extract by mask didn't execute.

Comment: I typed print raster on the shell, but it says that it is not defined.

Comment: That sounds like a new question so rather than change the existing one that is already answered would you normally be able to ask a new one, please?  The need for one question per question is in the [Tour] but in this case I spotted an additional error so have "extended" my answer.